# c2dm remove record from mysql when unregister

Tags: android, mysql, push-notification, android-c2dm

does anyone know how i could delete from my mysql db once a device has unregistered from c2dm?
i have in my main activity:

```
public void unregister (View view){
        Log.w("C2DM", "start unregister process");
        Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
        unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unregistered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        startService(unregIntent);
```

now here is my problem. when i register i enter device id and registration id into my mysql db (this works) i want to remove this once unregister is clicked

within my registration reciever i have

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
            Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
            final String registrationId = intent
                    .getStringExtra("registration_id");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

            Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                    + ", error = " + error);
            String deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            createNotification(context, registrationId);
            sendRegistrationIdToServer(deviceId, registrationId);
            // Also save it in the preference to be able to show it later
            saveRegistrationId(context, registrationId);}
```

sendRegistrationIdToServer is:

```
public void sendRegistrationIdToServer(String deviceId, String registrationId) {
        Log.d("C2DM", "Sending registration ID to my application server");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myserver.com/Sandbox/androidDevice.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            // Get the deviceID
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", deviceId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceID",   registrationId));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

onReceive and sendRegistrationIdtoserver are for when the device is registered. now from the above if i change the url of my php script (androidDevice.php) to my delete script the record is deleted from my database (when i click on the register button). so i know the script works.
is there something similar i could use to unregister like there is for registering?:

```
if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
```

(am i making any sence?)
any help as usual would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an `UNREGISTER` intent action that you can do. See [Google's C2DM page - unregistering](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#unregistering) for more information.